# how to manipulate array in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I want my script to define an empty array. array values should be added if predefined condition gets true. for this what i have done is

```
declare -a FILES
file_count=0
if [ "$file_ext" != "$SUPPORTED_FILE_TYPE" ] ; then
        echo "$file_ext is not supported for this task."
else
        $FILES[$file_count] = $filename
        file_count=$file_count+1
fi
```

when executing this script i am getting some error like this

```
linux-softwares/launchers/join_files.sh: 51: [0]: not found
```

Comment: For further reading on bash arrays take a look at http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When settings data in array does not recall with $:

```
declare -a FILES
file_count=0
if [ "$file_ext" != "$SUPPORTED_FILE_TYPE" ] ; then
        echo "$file_ext is not supported for this task."
else
        FILES[$file_count]=$filename
        file_count=$file_count+1
fi
```

FILES without $.

---

This works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a FILES
file_count=0

file_ext='jpg'
SUPPORTED_FILE_TYPE='jpg'
filename='test.jpg'

if [ "$file_ext" != "$SUPPORTED_FILE_TYPE" ] ; then
        echo "$file_ext is not supported for this task."
else
        FILES[$file_count]=$filename
        file_count=$(($file_count+1))
fi
```

As you see, a little modification $(( )) for math operation, but the FILES assignements is the same...

---

As pointed out after lots of tests, Ubuntu default shell seems to be dash, which raised the error.

Comment: Hi enrico, after removing that $ i am getting

    linux-softwares/launchers/join_files.sh: 51: FILES[0]: not found

what is this?

Comment: Remember your question of some minutes ago? Spaces hurts :) Just remove spaces after FILES[$file_count]

Comment: ohh yes. Sorry for the lost lesion. :)

Comment: The array assignment does not seems working  "FILES[$file_count]=$filename" results in a error message "files.sh: 61: FILES[0]=/home/vijay/reservoir.txt". Can you tell what is the problem.

Comment: It works for me. But not my script.How can i give my script to you?

Comment: Put it on pastebin.org, or edit your first post adding it to the end.

Comment: With the only edit http://pastebin.org/99313 highlighted, it works on my system... The error does not shows to me...

Comment: By the way, using single marks like VAR='$old_var' the expression is not evaulated, I mean, echo $VAR will show $old_var insted of it contents. Use double marks VAR="$old_var".

Comment: Does not works for me. Do you see any other reason of this. What error i get is "linux-softwares/launchers/join_files.sh: 60: FILES[0]=/home/vijay/downloads/Reservoir/Reservoir.avi: not found".

Comment: Is your file still like the one posted? 'Couse FILES[0] does not look to lie on the 60th line.
The version you posted works for me returning:
`$ ./99305.download 
Preparing to join avi files.
Enter file name > test.avi
You entered: test.avi .... Verifing file integrity.
Do you want to add more files. Please enter yes or no
no
preparing join command
Going to execute command mencoder -oac copy -ovc copy -o joined-output.avi
size = 1
Going to execute command mencoder -oac copy -ovc copy -o joined-output.avi
Going to execute command mencoder -oac copy -ovc copy -o joined-output.avi test.avi`

Comment: Any suggestion what may go wrong. This is my only second shell script. I am not able to contemplate anything. :(

Comment: http://pastebin.org/99420  This is the content form original file. I have added two echo statement for around array assignment.

Comment: Ok. Also this one is working for me. What is your default shell? ls -l /bin/sh points to bash?

Really I cannot understand what's the problem, it's working perfectly on my environment...

Comment: Hi, output of the your command
"vijay@vijay-laptop:~$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 2009-08-28 00:01 /bin/sh -> dash
"
is this okay. I am using default shell on ubuntu 9.10.

Comment: NOT DASH!  :) use bash, please! just set #!/bin/bash in the first line of your script, please!

Comment: Yes sir, That did worked, Thanks for all your helps. now reading for the differences between both. thanks again.

Comment: It has been a pleasure, and a new lesson for me... Avoid dash! :D

Answer (score 1):

To add an element to the end of an array, use the += operator (since bash 3.1 in 2004):

```
files+=( "$file" )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write it this way as well

```
declare -a FILES
file_count=0
if [ "$file_ext" != "$SUPPORTED_FILE_TYPE" ] ; then
        echo "$file_ext is not supported for this task."
else
        FILES[((file_count++))]=$filename
fi
```

To: Vijay

tiny demonstration, list *.txt files in directory and put to array FILES

```
declare -a FILES
i=0
for file in *.txt
do
  FILES[((i++))]=$file 
done
# display the array
for((o=0;o<${#FILES};o++))
do
    echo ${FILES[$o]} $o
done
```

output

```
$ ./shell.sh
A.txt 0
B.txt 1
file1.txt 2
file2.txt 3
file3.txt 4
```

Comment: this does not work. The error message is "files.sh: 39: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting ")")"

Comment: there's an extra "$" in variable FILES. remove it.

Comment: I did not get any $ where is that?

Comment: i already changed it. see my latest edit. originally, it was `$FILES[((file_count++))]=$filename`. which is wrong

Comment: see my edit demo. It works for me. Also you have accepted Enrico's answer, in his answer, he uses `FILES[$file_count]=$filename`, without the "$" sign. So i am puzzled why you still have problems.