# Manipulating an array (printed by php-cli) in shell script

Tags: linux, arrays, bash, shell, php

I am a newbie with shell scripts and I learnt a lot today.
This is an extension to this question [Assigning values printed by PHP CLI to shell variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376695/assigning-values-printed-by-php-cli-to-shell-variables)

I got the solution to read a variable in my shell script. Now how to manipulate an array? If I prepare an array in my PHP code and print it, and echo in my shell, it displays Array. How to access that array in the shell script? I tried the solution given in [how to manipulate array in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352530/how-to-manipulate-array-in-shell-script/2353298#2353298)

**With the following code:-**
*PHP code*

```
$neededConstants = array("BASE_PATH","db_host","db_name","db_user","db_pass");

$associativeArray = array();
foreach($neededConstants as $each)
{
    $associativeArray[$each] = constant($each);
}

print $associativeArray;
```

*Shell code*

```
function getConfigVals()
{
    php $PWD'/developer.php'
}




cd ..
PROJECT_ROOT=$PWD
cd developer

# func1 parameters: a b
result=$(getConfigVals)

for((cnt=0;cnt<${#result};cnt++))
do
    echo ${result[$cnt]}" - "$cnt
done
```

I get this output:-

```
Array - 0
 - 1
 - 2
 - 3
 - 4
```

Whereas I want to get this:-

```
Array
      BASE_PATH - /path/to/project
      db_host - localhost 
      db_name - database
      db_user - root 
      db_pass - root
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should debug your **PHP script** first to produce the valid array content, code

```
print $associativeArray;
```

will just get you the following output:

```
$ php test.php 
Array
```

You can simply print the associative array in a foreach loop:

```
foreach ( $associativeArray as $key=>$val ){
    echo "$key:$val\n";
}
```

giving a list of variable names + content separated by ':'

```
$ php test.php 
BASE_PATH:1
db_host:2
db_name:3
db_user:4
db_pass:5
```

---

As for the **shell script**, I suggest using *simple and understandable shell constructs* and then get to the advanced ones (like `${#result}`) to use them correctly.

I have tried the following bash script to get the variables from PHP script output to shell script:

```
# set the field separator for read comand
IFS=":"

# parse php script output by read command
php $PWD'/test.php' | while read -r key val; do
    echo "$key = $val"
done
```

Comment: Thanks and +1 for the suggestion of using simple and understandable shell constructs first and then get to the advanced ones

Answer (score 2):

With bash4, you can use mapfile to populate an array and process substitution to feed it:

```
mapfile -t array < <( your_command )
```

Then you can go through the array with:

```
for line in "${array[@]}"
```

Or use indices:

```
for i in "${#array[@]}"
do
   : use "${array[i]}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what shell you're using, but assuming it's one that supports arrays:

```
result=($(getConfigVals))    # you need to create an array before you can ...

for((cnt=0;cnt<${#result};cnt++))
do
    echo ${result[$cnt]}" - "$cnt    # ... access it using a subscript
done
```

This is going to be an indexed array, rather than an associative array. While associative arrays are supported in Bash 4, you'll need to use a loop similar to the one in Martin Kosek's answer for assignment if you want to use them.

Comment: @Sandeepan Nath: My answer applies to Bash.